# How to call local scope variable outside his function

Tags: jquery

Hi I have this code ajax and i want get var `respon`  but i cant do it in outside his function..

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

respon = [];
respon[0] = response;
respon[1] = respon[0].data.translations[0].translatedText;

    });
console.log(respon); // is not defined
```

Comment: Put: 'var respon;' as the first line. Then it will be defined.

Answer (score 0):

That's because ajax is an asynchronous call, meaning it takes some time before `response` is available.
In synchronous order this is what happens:

1. `$.ajax(settings)` gets called
2. `console.log(response)` gets called and isn't available yet => undefined
3. `response` becomes available when done

You can wrap `console.log()` in an outer scope function and call from the `done()` function

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    myCallback(response);
});

function myCallback(data){
    window.respon = []; // var respon = [];
    window.respon[0] = data;
    window.respon[1] = data[0].data.translations[0].translatedText;

    console.log(window.respon);
}
```

Now I've made it explicit that `respon` is part of the `window` object since you didn't declare it. It's not "really" necessary but it's what happens. If you don't need it anywhere else you should declare it and keep it in scope => use `var`, `let` or `const` depending on what you're planning to do with it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but the same problem is because I want her outside the function

Comment: Since you didn't declare `respon` outside the function it "becomes" part of the window object so it is available outside the function, just not when you want to call it. Perhaps you should fill us in on the idea why you need it outside the function and then we can help you better.